# VIF around 3.5 in two covariates, how shall I deal the problem?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

in my multinomial logistic regression model (sample size n=290) I am adjusting the results for a group of covariates (n=8). I tested them for multicollinearity and if most of them have a VIF lower than 2, two of them have the variance inflaction factor around 3.4. I know that the safest cut-off is 2.5 but some papers report also 5 as a valid cut-point. How shall I deal with it in my case? I would like to keep these covariates as they tell me something about the model and STATA did not exclude them running the model. How likely am I going to have problems if I state that all my covariates were tested for multicollinearity and all had a VIF lower than 3.5? 
Many thanks

edit: I added my output

[image]

Comment: Whether collinearity is a problem depends on your objectives as well as the actual results. You have done a good job describing these in general, but posting a summary of the coefficient estimates and their standard errors might encourage some readers to take a closer look and offer specific advice.

Comment: Not sure this qualifies as a full answer, but you could do a couple of things here: 1) Look at other measures of multicolinearity in addition to VIF. If no red flags come up using any other measures, and you feel that the covariates have a legitimate role in the model from a conceptual perspective, IMO you should generally be okay with 3.5 VIF. 2) If you're looking to publish this, take a look at other papers in the journals you're pitching your paper to and see what VIF values have made it into the final models. That should give you an idea of where reviewers and editors draw the line.